# "Do you consider yourself a member of the Stack Overflow community?" Question

Tags: discussion, survey, welcoming, community

Since when the "welcoming wagon" started, I have this little question in my mind:

Are answers to "Do you consider yourself a member of the Stack Overflow community?" really coherent to what we expect?

Why this is important? Well, we may be concluding incorrectly that [almost half](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2018/#engaging-together) of our users are not part of community for years...

Please, read both examples below and try to answer the following question as quickly you can.

Example 1: A user started 7 years ago in SO, comes here many times a week, votes many times a week, is thankful for staff work, is amazed by moderators job, feels sad for on going "problems", read meta posts and agree with most of meta heavy users complain...

Would **you** label this user as a part of community?

Example 2. A user also started 7 years ago, but doesn't create questions or answers often in main site, maybe in the last two years did not create a question or answer, neither in meta; doesn't have enough reputation to create a tag or edit topics; doesn't engage in chats, ...

Would **you** label this user as a part of community?

Got your answers? Are they the same?

Well, booth description can address the same user. In fact, they almost describe me. :)

Now let's go back to the survey. I'm almost sure that I did answer the survey differently over the time. When I look to example 2 above, I feel I'm not part of community. But when I look to example 1, it is clear for me that I am. The problem is: I often look to example 2.

I can't remember certainly, but it is possible that I started to answer that I feel that "I'm part of community" **just because** I did read that SO staff was feeling that many people are not part of SO community, that people that comes to meta it is not that important and etc...

Side note: I see that people are always relating welcoming and "be part of community". I'm not native English speaker, so can't be sure of this related to language but, in my point of view, they are not mutually exclusive. I can feel welcomed but not part of the community. I can also feel part of community but not feel welcomed.

TLDR: The question used in survey is ambiguous, not clearly defined. It is not clear what is the SO community. It is not clear what "be part of community" is. It is not clear what "feels" is indicating or even if it is important.

So please, don't use this question to conclude that people don't like SO, are not engaging or not feeling welcomed.

Comment: *"It is not clear what is the SO community."* - Depending on how you answer you may get a free-form answer question which asks you to explain why you answered the way you did... I simply defined what communities I felt were present and said which of those I felt I was a part of. In addition to this, I seem to recall "unsure" being an option, which seems to fit if you don't understand what community is being asked about

Comment: The open-ended nature may well be on purpose…!?

Comment: The question isn't whether **I** feel somebody else is part of the community. The question is whether **they** feel that themselves. And that's the thing with feelings - we can't really answer for somebody else. Another thing - we can't easily quantify feelings. Oh, also - it's often a lot more complex than "yes" or "no". We usually resolve ambiguities by explaining. Which is what the survey asks you to do in the next answer. You may participate *a lot* in community activities but *not* feel part of the community. This is not an oxymoron. You feel what you feel. Hopefully you can say why.

Comment: You are definitely part of the community, maybe not such an active part than others but still a part. That is unless you don't want to be part in which case of course please feel not being a part. Somehow I got the feeling that being part of a community is nothing binary but rather something continuous and quite complicated.

Comment: @deceze, Yes. And that *may* be a problem if we are using the answers to conclude we have a problem with people "don't feeling part of community".

Comment: @Trilarion, if it is ok to not feel part of community, why are we concerned that "people don't feel part of community"?

Comment: @VLAZ, Agree. I did wrote this: "I can feel welcomed but not part of the community. I can also feel part of community but not feel welcomed."

Comment: I mean... i think it's far more likely that question will be linked with demographic information than your actual usage of the site.

Comment: @EMBarbosa I'm not really concerned so much about that. And if I would then only about the cases where it limits what people can achieve here. If they are willingly not wanting to be part of it, I won't say anything against it.

Comment: @Trilarion *feeling* like you belong is definitely complicated. Let's make an absurd example to point it out. Say, there is a community that wears hats on Tuesdays. They take pride in that and it's what brings them together. Some might argue for correct hat eiquette, others just happy to participate. Then you have Fred who *happens* to wear hats on Tuesdays...because it's cold outside. While Fred participates in an activity that defines a community, Fred may not feel like he is part HatsOnTuesday. Fred might not even know the community exists, in fact.

Comment: @VLAZ That's not an absurd example, but probably a very real example that happens all the time. I rather like to think about practical impacts. Fred is perfectly happy, so let him be happy. But what if there was a community that consists of all people wearing hats on Tuesdays except those named Fred and Fred is aware of that and would like to be part of the community but can't. Therefore he isn't happy. That clearly makes a difference, while in the first case it doesn't change anything really whether you feel it or not, does it?

Comment: @Trilarion , maybe you are not concerned. But we know that SE is concerned. And is about that I'm talking.